# What is physics behind counter-steering?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

What is physics behind [counter-steering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countersteering)? When we drive bike, in order to achieve a sudden left turn, we turn the handlebars quickly to the right, and vice-versa. What is the physics behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We turn the handle bar quickly to the right in order to have left turn. Such strange phenomenon is called **counter steering**.

A bike always try to maintain no slip conditions, while making a turn of bike friction force generates torque in opposite direction, to counter it bikers lean the bike slightly. This is called normal steering.
In counter steering bikers take a slight quick turn in opposite direction to generate lean in desired direction and thus the bikers take turn in desired direction.

So the physics behind the phenomenon is torque action generated due to frictional force.